# How do I get the html from the web page that I am trying to scrape in a string?

Tags: web-scraping, httpclient, crystal-lang

I have written the following code:

```
require "http/client"
require "myhtml"

puts "Give me the URL of the page to be scraped."

url = gets

html=<<-HTML
 [Here goes the html of the website to be scraped]
HTML

myhtml = Myhtml::Parser.new(html)

myhtml.nodes(:div).each do |node|
  id = node.attribute_by("id")

  if first_link = node.scope.nodes(:a).first?
    href = first_link.attribute_by("href")
    link_text = first_link.inner_text

    puts "div with id #{id} have link [#{link_text}](#{href})"
  else
    puts "div with id #{id} have no links"
  end
end
```

How do I get the html from the webpage that I am trying to scrape in a string so that I can replace

```
html=<<-HTML
 [Here goes the html of the website to be scraped]
HTML
```

with something like

```
response = requests.get(url)

html = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
```

from the following Python code:

```
url = input("What is the address of the web page in question?\n")

response = requests.get(url)

html = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
```

or `let html = reqwest::get(url).await?.text().await?;` from the following Rust code:

```
println!("Give me the URL of the page to be scraped."); 
 let mut url = String::new();
 io::stdin().read_line(&mut url).expect("Failed to read line");

 let html = reqwest::get(url).await?.text().await?;
```

The documentation of the [shard myhtml](https://github.com/kostya/myhtml) does not provide enough
examples for me to figure this out.
Can it be done with [Crystal's HTTP client](https://crystal-lang.org/api/1.0.0/HTTP/Client.html) from their
standard library?
When I replaced

```
html=<<-HTML
 [Here goes the html of the website to be scraped]
HTML
```

with

```
response = HTTP::Client.get url

html = response.body
```

I get the following error:

```
response = HTTP::Client.get url #no overload matches 'HTTP::Client.get' with type (String | Nil)
                             ^--
Error: no overload matches 'HTTP::Client.get' with type (String | Nil)

Overloads are:
 - HTTP::Client.get(url : String | URI, headers : HTTP::Headers | ::Nil = nil, body : BodyType = nil, tls : TLSContext = nil)
 - HTTP::Client.get(url : String | URI, headers : HTTP::Headers | ::Nil = nil, body : BodyType = nil, tls : TLSContext = nil, &block)
 - HTTP::Client.get(url, headers : HTTP::Headers | ::Nil = nil, tls : TLSContext = nil, *, form : String | IO | Hash)
 - HTTP::Client.get(url, headers : HTTP::Headers | ::Nil = nil, tls : TLSContext = nil, *, form : String | IO | Hash, &block)
Couldn't find overloads for these types:
 - HTTP::Client.get(Nil)
```

I am able to get the text from the web page
by hard coding it, e.g. `response = HTTP::Client.get "https://github.com/monero-project/monero/releases"`
but that would no suffice as I want the app to be interactive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close, it is the type system that is complaining. `HTTP::Client.get` expects a `String` (or rather `String | URL`). However, in your code your `url` variable can also be `nil` and is of type `String?`, which is short for `String | Nil`. If you hard-code the URL, it cannot be `nil` but is always of type `String`. Therefore the `HTTP::Client.get` call works.

Check out the [documentation of the `get` function](https://crystal-lang.org/api/1.0.0/IO.html#gets(chomp=true):String?-instance-method):

> def gets(chomp = true) : String?
>
> Reads a line from this IO. A line is terminated by the \n character. Returns nil if called at the end of this IO.

There are multiple ways to address it, but the basic idea is that you have to make sure that `url` cannot be `nil` when you make the HTTP call. For example:

```
url = gets
if url
  # now url cannot be nil
  response = HTTP::Client.get url
  html = response.body
  puts html
end
```

Further reading: [if var](https://crystal-lang.org/reference/syntax_and_semantics/if_var.html)